# how to subtract a number in a specific position in dataframe from every value in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, difference, tibble

I have a dataframe with 216 rows and 12 columns and I am trying to add a new column where each value is equal to the difference between each element in the 12th column and the value of the element in the 216th row, 12th column (df[216,12]). When I tried doing this with a reduced version of the dataframe (i.e. with just 5 columns instead of 216) it worked without problems but now that I'm trying to do the exact thing on the full dataset, it gives me an error saying "Error in Ops.data.frame(df_final[, 12], df_final[216, 12]) :‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames". Not sure why I'm getting that error or how to fix it..

For illustrative purposes, a simplified version of my dataset is as follows (the code works for this simplified dataset but not for my full dataset with 216 rows instead of just 5):

```
miRNA<-c("hsa-miR-10a-4373153", "hsa-miR-10b-4395329", "MammU6-4395470_1", "MammU6-4395470_2", "hsa-miR-15a-4373123")
C1<-c(28.005966, 30.806433, 17.341375, 17.40666, 30.039436)
T2<-c(30.973469, 29.236025, 30.41161, 20.914383, 20.904331)
C3<-c(26.322796, 25.542833, 22.460772, 19.972183, 30.409641)
T4<-c(26.441898, 25.837685, 23.158352, 20.379173, 33.81327)
C5<-c(39.750206, 19.901133, 28.180124, 22.668673, 25.748884)
T6<-c(23.004385, 28.472675, 23.81621, 26.433413, 28.851719)
T7<-c(22.239546, 28.741674, 23.754929, 26.015385, 28.16368)
T8<-c(29.590443, 30.041988, 21.323061, 24.272501, 18.099016)
C9<-c(15.856442, 22.64224, 29.629637, 25.374926, 22.356894)
C10<-c(38.137985, 24.753338, 26.986668, 24.578161, 19.223558)
data<-data.frame(miRNA, C1, T2, C3, T4, C5, T6, T7, T8, C9, C10)
View(data)
data$C12<-data[,11]-data[5,11]
```

Comment: I just edited my post, I realised it hadn't included the miRNA vector the first time. It should work now

Comment: I am not getting any error now and it is working as expected.  Can you post a reproducible small example that shows the issue as I don't find an issue here

Comment: Yes, that's what exactly what confuses me. Like I said above, when I try to do this operation on a simplified version of my dataset (with just 5 rows, instead of 216), it works just fine but when I try the exact same thing on my full dataset (with 216 rows), it gives me the error ""Error in Ops.data.frame(df_final[, 12], df_final[216, 12]) :‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames".

Comment: Can you check the `str(df_final)`. Is it a `data.frame` or `tbl_df` or `data.table`

Comment: ```> str(df_final)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 216 obs. of  13 variables:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that it is a `tbl_df`.  Unlike `data.frame`, `data[,11]` won't collapse to a `vector`.  It is still a tbl_df with a single column.  There are many options

```
unlist(data[,11])- unlist(data[5,11])
```

Using a reproducible example

```
df1 <- tibble(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
df1[, 2] - df1[1, 2]
```

> Error in Ops.data.frame(df1[, 2], df1[1, 2]) : 
>         ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

```
unlist(df1[,2]) - unlist(df1[1,2])
```

Or with `drop = TRUE` which is by default `FALSE` in tibble`whereas in`data.frame`, it is`TRUE`

```
df1[[2]] - df1[1,2, drop = TRUE]
```

Note here that we use `[[` to extract the column as a `vector`

Or another option is to make use of `dplyr` functions

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(2, ~ . - .[2])
```

Comment: Oh I see now. Yep, unlisting it definitely did the trick, thank you very much for your help!